Kubernetes CKS Killercoda broken scenario?
I am not sure about where to post this, but I am unable to pass the second step of this scenario: https://killercoda.com/killer-shell-cks/scenario/secret-etcd-encryption
I checked 300 times and everything seems coorect. I googled to see if the question is bugged but could not find any relevant match.
Does anyone care to try it out and let me know if it works for them?
